# Multi Tenancy Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, multi-tenant, quartz

I have a backend spring boot application that has a quartz scheduler with multiple job triggers working all good but now we got a new client who wants the exact same solution so in order to support this we choose multi-tenancy by SEPERATE SCHEMA approach so each client/tenant will now have his own schema but I am not sure on how do we have quartz running in each schema individually.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you explore on the use of the `Custom ConnectionProvider Implementations` in Quartz, wherein, we can provide a custom connection provider that can look up the database of your application to identify the tenant specific connection string and then return to Quartz to be used.

This will allow you to use multiple connections based on some tenancy data.

More [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/configuration.html#configuration-of-jdbc-jobstoretx-store-jobs-and-triggers-in-a-database-via-jdbc)